# Symfony 5 Form mutates user in session

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

**The issue:** I am having this issue where if the user submits an email to my user form that is already used they get an error message (like they are supposed to). After they get the error if the page is refreshed or they navigate to another page on the site the user gets logged out, I think the user is already logged out after they receive the form back with the error but the page is still rendered like the user is logged in.

The user entity doesn't have a username field and uses the email as visual identifier.

**Summary**: after user form failed uniqueEntity validation user gets logged out on next request,

**The question**: Is there any way I can prevent this behavior?

**UPDATE:** it seems the form is calling setters of the user entity when you try to update the email regardless of whether it is valid or not. the user that is stored in the session is mutated and then after the next request it does not match the user in the database and needs to authenticate again. This is a bug that occurs only when the object of the current user is put into the form. the question remains the same.

Down here I will include all the code needed to reproduce this issue.

The user class:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"},
 *     message="general.unique_email"
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="general.not_blank")
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="general.not_blank")
     * @Assert\LessThan(
     *     value="-16 years",
     *     message="general.min_age"
     * )
     */
    private $birthDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="general.not_blank")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min="10",
     *     minMessage="general.characters_min",
     *     max="15",
     *     maxMessage="general.characters_max",
     * )
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="general.not_blank")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min="2",
     *     minMessage="general.characters_min",
     *     max="30",
     *     maxMessage="general.characters_max",
     * )
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min="2",
     *     minMessage="general.characters_min",
     *     max="20",
     *     maxMessage="general.characters_max",
     * )
     */
    private $prepositions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="general.not_blank")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min="2",
     *     minMessage="general.characters_min",
     *     max="30",
     *     maxMessage="general.characters_max",
     * )
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $gender;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(?string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(?array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(?string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getBirthDate(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthDate;
    }

    public function setBirthDate(?DateTimeInterface $birthDate): self
    {
        $this->birthDate = $birthDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(?string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(?string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrepositions(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prepositions;
    }

    public function setPrepositions(?string $prepositions): self
    {
        $this->prepositions = $prepositions;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(?string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGender(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    public function setGender(?bool $gender): self
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The form class:

```php
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'user.email',
            ])
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'user.first_name',
            ])
            ->add('prepositions', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'user.prepositions',
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'user.last_name'
            ])
            ->add('phone', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'user.phone',
            ])
            ->add('birthDate', BirthdayType::class, [
                'label' => 'user.birth_date',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'placeholder' => [
                    'day' => 'general.day',
                    'month' => 'general.mon th',
                    'year' => 'general.year',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'user.gender.label',
                'choices' => [
                    'user.gender.male' => true,
                    'user.gender.female' => false,
                    'user.gender.other' => null,
                ]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'form',
        ]);
    }
}
```

The controller:

```php
    /**
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
     * @Route("/account", name="account")
     */
    public function account(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $userForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $userForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userForm->isSubmitted() && $userForm->isValid()) {
            $this->addFlash('success', 'applied user data');
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_security_account');
        }

        $passwordForm = $this->createForm(ChangePasswordType::class);
        $passwordForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($passwordForm->isSubmitted() && $passwordForm->isValid()) {
            /** @var ChangePassword $changePassword */
            $changePassword = $passwordForm->getData();
            $this->getUser()->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($this->getUser(), $changePassword->getNewPassword()));
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'changed password');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_security_account');
        }

        return $this->render('page/security/account.html.twig', [
            'title' => 'My Site | Account',
                'userForm' => $userForm->createView(),
                'passwordForm' => $passwordForm->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

The twig template:

```html
{% extends 'content_base.html.twig' %}

{% block content_container %}
    <h1>{{ 'user.header'|trans([], 'form') }}</h1>
    {{ form_start(userForm, {"novalidate": "novalidate"}) }}
        {{ form_widget(userForm) }}
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    {{ form_end(userForm) }}
    <h1>{{ 'password.header'|trans([], 'form') }}</h1>
    {{ form_start(passwordForm, {"novalidate": "novalidate"}) }}
        {{ form_widget(passwordForm) }}
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    {{ form_end(passwordForm) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Security.yaml:

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_security_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: app_security_login
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path: /
```

Comment: I wouldn't change the email adress in the same form as everything else. Also, I would likely not use the live user object in a form. at least you should add constraints to your email field in the form (read up on the form constraints).

Answer (score 0):

Because of the inherit design flaw of security and binding entities to forms there is no real fix that'd allow me to keep the same design so I will have to figure out how to deal with this. I think the solution will be to make a custom form to handle the email so it doesn't effect the current entity.